# FormGroup updating FormControl value for radios immediately when they are added

Tags: angular, angular5

## The Problem

When adding radio-type inputs to `FormGroup` the value for the `FormControl` is updated immediately. In addition, changing the selected radio button does not update the `FormControl` value.

## The Code

My code is a dynamic form system using a service (`FormService`) to maintain a singleton `FormGroup` with functions to add and remove inputs as necessary.

All of my inputs extend a base input class called `InputBaseComponent` that imports `FormService` and creates a form control for itself and adds it to the `FormGroup` via the service. The `InputBaseComponent` also contains all of the generic functionality that is the same across all inputs.

#### `FormService`

The form service is a pretty generic service that regulates the `FormGroup` with getter/setter functions. This service is imported by `InputBaseComponent` which is extended by each individual input component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class FormService {

    // An arry of all the inputs in the form
    inputs: any[] = [];

    // The form group for this instance of the form service singleton
    formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

    // Adds an input to the array of inputs in the form
    addInput( input: any ){

        // Push the input to the array if it's not already in the inputs array
        if ( this.inputs.indexOf(input) === -1 ) this.inputs.push(input);

        // Push the input's form control to the form group if it doesn't already exist
        if ( !this.formGroup.contains(input.name) ) this.formGroup.addControl(input.name, input.formControl);
    }

    // Removes an input from the array of inputs in the form
    removeInput( input: any ){

        // Remove the input from the array if it exists
        this.inputs.filter( arrayInput => arrayInput !== input);

        // Remove the control from the form group
        if ( this.formGroup.contains(input.name) ) this.formGroup.removeControl(input.name);
    }
}
```

#### `BaseInputComponent`

This is the base input component that all of the actual input components extend.  This is done to keep all general functionality in one place to keep from repeating code for each input.  I have truncated all of the inputs at the end for simplicities sake, but trust me they are there.

```
// ---------- Imports ---------- //

    import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, Validators, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

    /// ---------- Dependencies ---------- ///

        import { FormService } from "../form.service";

// ---------- Components ------- //
    @Component({
        selector: 'input-base-component-do-not-use-directly',
        template: ``
    })
    export class InputBaseComponent implements OnInit {

        /// ---------- Constructor ---------- ///

            constructor ( public formService: FormService ){};

        /// ---------- Properties ----------- ///

            // A reference to this form input's form control
            formControl: any;

        /// ---------- Methods -------------- ///

            // On init set up the form control with the proper validators
            ngOnInit() {

                // Setup the form control with the proper validators
                this.setupFormControl( this.getValidators() );
            }

            // Creates an array of all of the validator functions that should apply to the input and returns it
            getValidators(): ValidatorFn[] {

                // Create the validators array
                let validators: any[] = [];

                // Set the max length validator
                if (this.maxLength) validators.push(Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength));

                // Set the min length validator
                if ( this.minLength ) validators.push(Validators.minLength(this.minLength));

                // Set the required validator
                if ( this.required ) validators.push(Validators.required);

                // Include any custom validators
                if ( this.customValidators && this.customValidators.length ) validators = validators.concat(this.customValidators);

                // Return the array of validator functions
                return validators;
            }

            // Sets up the form control and adds it to the form service
            setupFormControl( validators: ValidatorFn[] ): void {

                // Create the form control for this input
                if (this.formService.formGroup.contains(this.name)) {
                    this.formControl = this.formService.formGroup.get(this.name)
                } else {
                    this.formControl = this.getNewFormControl( validators );
                    this.formService.addInput(this);
                }

                // Update the parent component whenever this input's value is changed
                this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe( newValue => this.valueChange.emit(newValue));

                // Add the input to the form group
                this.formService.addInput(this);
            }

            // Takes an array of validator functions and returns a new form control with all of the proper setup for this input
            getNewFormControl( validators: ValidatorFn[] ): FormControl {

                // Return a new form control for this form
                return new FormControl( this.value || null, { validators: validators, updateOn: this.validateOn } );
            }
    }
```

#### Code of interest

If you look at the following lines of the `setupFormControl` function you can see that we are checking the `FormGroup` to see if there is already a `FormControl` with the name given for the input, as is the case for radio buttons and checkboxes.  If it does already exist, it uses that existing `FormControl` as the form control for the input.  This was done to mimic the proper markup for using radio buttons and checkboxes with reactive forms, where-in each radio or checkbox in a group uses the same form control.

```
// Create the form control for this input
if (this.formService.formGroup.contains(this.name)) {
    this.formControl = this.formService.formGroup.get(this.name)
} else {
    this.formControl = this.getNewFormControl( validators );
    this.formService.addInput(this);
}
```

The markup implementing this code is as follows:

```
<!-- input -->
<input 
    #input 
    [formControl]="formControl" 
    [type]="type" 
    [name]="name" 
    [id]="idStr" 
    [value]="value" 
    tabindex="-1" 
/>
```

## The Possible Solution

As stated before, with this setup as soon as the form control is added (or re-used on those past the first radio/checkbox) the value of the `FormControl` instance is updated to the last added radio or checkbox. In addition anytime the selected radio or checkbox(es) is changed, the value of the `FormControl` is not updated.

#### The desired functionality

The desired functionality here is that the `FormControl` instance's `value` property would remain as `null` until a user selects a radio or checkbox. In addition, when changing the selected radio or checkbox(es) the value of the `FormControl` should update.

Comment: You can remove `[value]="value"` and share what exactly behavior you see.

Comment: The value is not updated, as expected, however the value is not updated upon interaction with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two answers here, one for the value, and another for the value not updating.

## Why the value was being applied

If you look at the function `getNewFormControl`, you have this line of code:

```
// Return a new form control for this form
return new FormControl( this.value || null, { validators: validators, updateOn: this.validateOn } );
```

This line needed to be updated to take into account not setting the value for checkboxes and radio buttons, so a simple check using a ternary fixes the issue:

```
// Return a new form control for this form
return new FormControl( this.type !== "radio" && this.type !== "checkbox" ? this.value || null : null, { validators: validators, updateOn: this.validateOn } );
```

## Why the value was not updating

There is a known bug in Angular 2+ regarding dynamic input types for radio and checkbox. For these input types, you cannot have a dynamic type applied to the input.

This code will work correctly:

```
<!-- input -->
<input 
    #input 
    [formControl]="formControl" 
    type="radio" 
    [name]="name"
    [value]="value"
/>
```

This code will not work at all:

```
<!-- input -->
<input 
    #input 
    [formControl]="formControl" 
    [type]="myInputType" 
    [name]="name"
    [value]="value"
/>
```

Unfortunately this means using `ngIf` and two separate inputs that then need to be updated separately. This has been a known bug since Angular 2 RC.6, it would be nice if they would fix it.